# Is there any way to change the value of an object property dynamically? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong, but still is there any way I can set a value according to the window size?

Here is a sample code:

```
var setNewValue;
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() < 768) {
    setNewValue = "less";
  } else {
    setNewValue = "more";
  }
});

var createObject = function(property) {
  this.property = property;
  this.showProperty = function() {
    document.write(this.property);
  };
};

var example = new createObject(setNewValue);
example.showProperty();
```

// undefined

Comment: Are you resizing the window to trigger the event handler?

Comment: Yes, the value must be set according to window size

Comment: `setNewValue` and `property` are no objects. That's why there is no reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var createObject = function(property) {
  return {
    property: property,
    getProperty: function() {
      return this.property;
    }
  };
};

var example = createObject();

$(window).resize(function() {
  example.property = $(window).width() < 768 ? "less" : "more";
  document.write(example.getProperty());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But it also gives undefined with resize function

Comment: @MykytaKhilai recheck it, please

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a race condition here. When the script is run, what's happening is that:

1. `setNewValue` variable is defined (it's value is `undefined` at the moment)
2. resize event handler is defined
3. `createObject()` is called with current `setNewValue` value which is still `undefined`

Unless there is no resize event triggered between steps 2. and 3., you'll always end up with `setNewValue = undefined` when calling `createObject()`.

I'm not sure what's the big picture here as you've posted only a snippet of your code, but you need to make sure that `setNewValue` variable is already set when accessing it -- for example by explicitly setting it somewhere at the beginning of the script.